# Call pl/sql function in java?

Tags: java, oracle, function, jdbc, plsql

So I've got a function that checks how many cancellations are in my booking table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_cancellations
RETURN number IS
   t_canc number := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into t_canc
   FROM booking where status = 'CANCELLED';
   RETURN t_canc;
END;
/
```

To execute his in sql I use:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
   c number;
BEGIN
   c := total_cancellations();
   dbms_output.put_line('Total no. of Cancellations: ' || c);
END;
/
```

My result is:

```
anonymous block completed
Total no. of Cancellations: 1
```

My question is can someone help me call the function in JAVA, I have tried but with no luck.

Comment: I want to learn from your mistakes. Please share the `Java` code.

Comment: if the function is that simple and doesn't modify datas, you can also use a traditional `PreparedStatement` with "`select total_cancellations() from dual`".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Java provides [`CallableStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) for such purposes .

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL total_cancellations()}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.setInt(2, acctNo);
cstmt.executeUpdate();
int cancel= cstmt.getInt(1);
System.out.print("Cancellation is "+cancel);
```

will print the same as you do in the pl/sql. As per docs [`Connection#prepareCall()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String)),

> Creates a CallableStatement object for calling database stored procedures. The CallableStatement object provides methods for setting up its IN and OUT parameters, and methods for executing the call to a stored procedure.

You can also pass parameters for the function . for ex ,

```
conn.prepareCall("{? = CALL total_cancellations(?)}");
cstmt.setInt(2, value);
```

will pass the values to the function as input parameter.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This does help and is what ive been trying to do where im struggling is to initialize the seInt to the right value. Where you have acctNo in the setInt i dont know what to put here or how to initialize it.

Answer (score 5):

> **Prepare a Callable Statement**
>
> There are two formats available, the
>   familiar block syntax used by Oracle and the ANSI 92 standard syntax.
>   In the case of our sample program, the block syntax has the form:
>               `CallableStatement vStatement = 
>           vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall( "begin ? := javatest( ?, ? ); end;" );`
>
> The ANSI 92 syntax has the form:
>
> ```
>    CallableStatement vStatement = 
>            vDatabaseConnection.prepareCall( "{ ? = call javatest( ?, ? )}");
> ```

[source](http://everythingoracle.com/plsqlfrjv.htm)

If you receive the below error, you might want to use the first format.

> *total_cancellations is not a procedure or is undefined error.*

Sample code.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xxx.xx.xxx:1521:xxx", "user","pass");
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("begin ? := TEST_FUNC(?,?); end;");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cstmt.setString(2, "Test");
cstmt.setInt(3, 1001);
cstmt.execute();
int result = cstmt.getInt(1);
System.out.print("Result: " + result);
cstmt.close();
conn.close();
```