# How to call PL/SQL function without parameters in java

Tags: java, plsql

Ive got a function, which returns VARCHAR, but has no parameters on start, it looks like this:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION stosunek_platnosci RETURN VARCHAR
IS
liczba_oplaconych NUMBER;
liczba_nieoplaconych NUMBER;
komentarz Varchar(135);
oplacone Varchar(1) := 'T';
begin
 Select count(*) into liczba_oplaconych from rezerwacje where platnosc_dokonana = oplacone; 
 Select count(*) into liczba_nieoplaconych from rezerwacje where platnosc_dokonana != oplacone; 
 if liczba_oplaconych > liczba_nieoplaconych then           
    komentarz:= 'Obecnie klienci w większości opłacili swoje rezerwacje.';
 elsif liczba_oplaconych < liczba_nieoplaconych then            
    komentarz:= 'Obecnie klienci w większości nie opłacili swoich rezerwacji.';
 else
    komentarz:= 'W bazie jest tyle samo opłaconych i nieopłaconych rezerwacji.';
 end if;
RETURN komentarz;
end;
```

and call it like this:

```
try {
        callStmt = connection.prepareCall("{stosunek_platnosci();}");
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
        callStmt.execute();
        jTextField1.setText(callStmt.getString(1));
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Stats.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and finally it doesn't work... Can u help me?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You can check out issue at the bottom, maybe it helps. [Call pl/sql function in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26550465/call-pl-sql-function-in-java)

Comment: The error is: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION xyz RETURN VARCHAR
IS
k Varchar(135);
begin
    k:= 'abc';
RETURN k;
end;
```

and

```
    CallableStatement call = conn.prepareCall("{? = call xyz()}");
    call.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    call.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(call.getString(1));
```

see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call5.htm

Comment: glad to know that :-)